# Percona Xtrabackup (Partial + incremental)

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, xtrabackup

we have been trying restore Percona (Partial + Incremental) mysql backup, but failing. The process followed is as below:

**For Backup**

# Step I: Take Partial-Full Backup

```
    innobackupex --user=root --password=**** --databases="db1" /path/to/basebackupdir --no-timestamp
```

# Step II: Take Partial-Incremental Backup

```
    innobackupex --incremental /path/to/incbackupdir --databases="db1" --incremental-basedir=/path/to/basebackupdir/ --user=root --password=**** --no-timestamp
```

**For Restoration**

## Step I: apply log to full backup

```
 innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only fullbackup
```

## Step II: apply-log incremental backup

```
innobackupex --apply-log fullbackup --incremental-dir=/tmp/tmp_inc
```

## Step III: Export Backup

```
innobackupex --apply-log --export fullbackup
```

## Step IV: CREATE Required database in MySQL

```
mysql -uroot -p**** -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db1"
mysql -uroot -p**** -e "CREATE DATABASE db1"
```

## Step V: Import DATABASE Structure

```
mysql -uroot -p**** db1 < db1.sql
```

## Step VI: Discard tablespace

## Step VII: Import table

```
    cd /tmp/fullbackup/db1
    cp -R *.ibd /var/lib/mysql/db1
    cp -R *.cfg /var/lib/mysql/db1
```

## Step VIII: Import tablespace

## Step IX: restart mysql

```
    service mysql restart
```

Restoration process works fine, Still we are failing, that One of the tables could not create the structure for FULLTEXT index(it gets corrupted), when we try to create table manually error is table already exists.

**Please Help**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you import the tablespaces? Strickly speaking you could use the data from step II, move it in the datadir, adjust the permissions and start MySQL. The procedure you using would make sense only if you want to restore db1 out of many other databases.  What is the error message?  Anything specific regarding the table that is failing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I am trying to restore only db1 out of many other databases. Also the error i am facing is regarding indexes, a full text type index is failing the table creation.